# address of characters in C++

Tags: c++, character

I have this program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char c;
    c = 'A';
    cout<<"c = "<<c<<" &c = "<<&c<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the conosol to print out the following statement:
c = A &c = address in hex format

but instead I get this:
[image]

(Output: &c = A0 ")

why does the compiler treats the address of a character as an ASCII code, not a hex number

Comment: Here's a hint: What is the type of a C character string? What is the type of `&c`?

Comment: yes c is a char variable, &c is the address of c, the "A0 " " is probably the ASCII code of the address, but my question is why does &c returns an ASCII string, were if c was an integer, &c will retrun the address in hex format

Comment: the type of &c is "pointer to char", same as C string. So it prints the character A and everything that is after it in memory until null character is encountered

Comment: yes, that helped alot, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "<<" operator is defined for char and char* to write a "character sequence" so if you want to see the address You have to cast to the number **(int)&c**